# How to get img element as well formed

Tags: javascript, html

I have well formed html with image tag as

```
<img src="" width="400" height="100"/>
```

But when I got it through getElementById innerHTML the image tag becomes ill formed:

```
<img src="" width="400" height="100">
```

Here is a small page for testing

```
<html>
    <body>
    <article id="a1">
        <img src="" width="400" height="100"/>
    </article>

    <script>
        alert(document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML);
    </script>
    <body>
</html>
```

How can I get img tag well formed from dom tree?
I tried declare html as xhtml but it does not help.

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ke4z02x3/

Comment: ...what makes you think it matters? If that's what the DOM constructs from well-formed (X)HTML, then what's the problem?

Comment: _“How can I get img tag well formed from dom tree?”_ – what for? What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: What for? I send html content to another servlet that gives me it back as pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `innerHTML` as it's not reliable. You should be serializing the code instead.

```
alert(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById('a1')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers (at least Chrome and Firefox, I haven't tested any further) will give you well-formed markup in `innerHTML` so long as they are in XML mode.

This is trigged by an XML **content-type HTTP header** (such as `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml`), not an XHTML Doctype (which is used only as a string of Standards Mode Invokation).

They will also include markup to specify the namespaces in use though.