# Getting html content using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below example.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_set

Here I am taking Html as string using Jquery html() method.
On click of `hello` button, It gives below output.

```
<button>hello</button>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3frontimage.png">
```

Here if we look at `<img>` tag, it is ignoring end `</img>` tag.

How can i get output as

```
<button>hello</button>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3frontimage.png"></img>
```

Thanks!

Comment: img is a self closing tag

Comment: <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3frontimage.png" />

Comment: You cant get like that since Image tag is a self closing tag . Actually what do you want to output from an image tag?

Comment: img is one of the self closing tags it doenst need a closing tag like `<h1>` or `<p>`

Comment: Strictly speaking, h1 and p also don't _need_ closing tag. It is just recommended to do it (I'm talking html-wise)

Comment: The end tag is required for `h1`, optional for `p` and forbidden for `img` (in HTML).

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920541/how-to-get-img-element-as-well-formed/25920659#25920659

Comment: @Quentin , what would be the answer? Or why dont you close/delete the question?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird — I don't really want to spend time explaining edge cases in the SO moderation system.

Comment: @Quentin ,then why is it like i m getting -3 but  `user1680977` got no downvotes ? IF you treat it like comment , i explained better.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird — I can't read the minds of other SO users!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `</img>`. Img tag is only written as `<img ... >` (or as `<img ... />` in xhtml)

Comment: `<img></img>` is perfectly valid in XHTML.